# How to pass a parameter in an expectation to the return value in Rhino Mocks?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I want to mock this interface:

```
interface IA {
  IB DoSomething(IC arg)
}
```

in a way that simulates an implementation like this:

```
class A : IA {
    public IB DoSomething(IC arg) { return new B(arg); }
}
```

How can I do that?
From other similar questions, it's supposed to be something like this:

```
MockRepository.GenerateMock<IA>().Expect(x => x.DoSomething(null)).IgnoreArguments().Callback<IC>(arg => new B(arg))
```

But i can't get it to work. I'm using RhinoMocks 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a typesafe example:

```
var mockA = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IA>();
mockA
    .Stub(x => x.DoSomething(Arg<IC>.Is.Anything))
    .Do((Func<IC, IB>)(arg => new B(arg)))
    .Return(null);
```

Comment: Thanks, while not ideal, that's slightly better

Answer (score 1):

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IA>();
mock
  .Stub(x => x.DoSomething(Arg<IC>.Is.Anything)
  // return a new instance of B each time
  .WhenCalled(call => call.ReturnValue = new B((IC)call.Arguments[0]))
  // make rhino mock validation happy
  .Return(null);
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Is there any type safe way to do it without having to do the explicit cast?